Type-hint result of Prisma ORM "findUnique" method
I'm pretty new using TypeScript and understand the strong concept of type-hinting. But it can be somewhat overwhelming. I am using Prisma ORM in a TypeScript project using express, and i have some issue using the result of findUnique method. Let me expalain.
I've created a simple user model:
// prisma/schema/user.prisma

model User {
  id            String @id @default(cuid())
  firstname     String
  lastname      String
  email         String @unique
  password      String
  salt          String?
  sessionToken  String? @unique
}

I have then an helper file that perform all needed operations like get users, create, and so on. Let's take for example the function that retrieve an user by it's email.
// src/helpers/users.ts

export const getUserByEmail = (email: string) => prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { email },
})

Finally, i have kind of a controller that perform login action and in this file i'm retrieving the user by it's email and check the password hash
// src/controllers/authentication.ts

export const login = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body

        if (!email || !password) {
            res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        }

        let user = await getUserByEmail(email)

        if (!user) {
            return res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        }

        const expectedHash = authentication(user.salt, password)

        // ...

        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(user).end()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }
}

So,my problem lies here: user.salt as i get unresolved variable salt. I've tried to tell that i want a User as response but didn't work.
import { User } from '@prisma/client'

// ...

let user: User | null = await getUserByEmail(email)

But i have a long error saying Initializer type Prisma__UserClient<$Result.GetResult<Prisma.$UserPayload<$Extensions.DefaultArgs>, {where: {email: string}}, "findUnique"> | null, null, $Extensions.DefaultArgs> is not assignable to variable type User | null
I'm a bit confused with this long type with lots subtypes and/or variables, it may be simple but for now i'm lost. Can you please explain me what did i miss ?

This should work, you don't have to use the type assertion let user: User | null for this:
// src/helpers/users.ts

export const getUserByEmail = (email: string) => prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: { email },
    include: { salt: true }
});


salt il already include in the response because i don't filter with select, and include is for relationships not for an attribute already in the model. But the code i posted works, juste the IDE telle me thant i can be more precise about the return type and i'd like to understand more precisely what's wrong

findUnique return type doesn't match the User type, perhaps because of missing required properties. If you follow the error message down to last sentence, you will find properties that do not match
